# Text input blurs after focusing in Firefox in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I have a text input:

```
{this.state.showInput 
    && (<input
        type="number"
        min="0"
        max="5"
        onKeyPress={this.onPressKey}
        onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
        onBlur={e => this.revertValue(e)}
        defaultValue={this.props.initialMark}
        ref={this.inputRef}
    />)
}
```

By default `showInput` is false. And with click on a button I do:

```
this.setState({ showInput: true }, () => {
    if (this.inputRef.current)
        this.inputRef.current.focus();
});
```

And with onBlur I revert `showInput` value to false:

```
revertValue(e) {
    e.target.value = this.props.initialMark;
    this.setState({ showInput: false });
}
```

The issue is why just after triggering onFocus I see on blur is triggered, so my input doesn't appear? How can I avoid this behavior?

This relates to Firefox only.

Comment: im also getting this... here is a fiddle with example https://jsfiddle.net/zj04butg/6/

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the strange behavior *(bug in other words)* of `<input type="number">` in [firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1057858) itself rather than [React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11062). Firefox triggers `onBlur` immediately after `.focus()` was called on the **newly created element** with `type="number"`. Of course you can replace a `type="number"` to the `type="text"`, but this is not a good way to fix the problem.

Depending on the situation (or preferences) there are two options.

**[Click here to see demos.](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww809p6vxk)**

1. **Asynchronously**. Just wrap your `this.inputRef.current.focus();` into *setTimeout*, like this `setTimeout(() => this.inputRef.current.focus(), 100);`. And 100 ms after the input was created that input get focused.
2. Or **synchronously**, which I prefer more.

For this case you need additional property in component state, e.g. `initialized: false`.

Next, you need to set `initialized` to **true** in `onBlur` handler *(or revertValue in your example)*, this code will be working only in firefox, because of strange behavior, about which I wrote above.

```
if (!this.state.initialized) {
  return this.setState({
    initialized: true,
  });
}
```

And at the last step you need to "reset" this property for other browser using this code after *.focus()*. Notice that this is an asynchronous call.

```
this.setState(() => ({
  initialized: true,
}));
```